# Probability getting a certain number a minimum number of times

Tags: probability

If you roll $3$ six-sided dices six separate times, what are the odds of getting *at least* one $18$?

Is it just sum of probabilities (probability of getting just $1 \times 18 + $ prob of getting $2\times 18$ ...)

$$\sum_1^6\left(\frac{1}{6^3}\right)^i$$

Comment: You could describe this as the probability of getting **exactly one** 18 (*and five numbers different than 18*) + prob of getting **exactly two** 18's (*and four numbers different than 18*) etc... these numbers can be found using binomial distribution rather straightforwardly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to calculate the probability of getting at least one 18 is by first calculating the probability of not getting any $18$'s.

This would be $\left({215 \over 216}\right)^6$.  Therefore, the probability of getting at least one $18$ is $1-\left({215 \over 216}\right)^6$.

You could instead add together the probability of getting exactly one $18$ plus the probability of getting two $18$'s, etc.., however the formula to calculate each of those individual probabilities is not as simple as the formula you have written.  (For example, the formula for exactly two $18$'s is not simply $\left({215 \over 216}\right)^2$ because this only calculates the first two rolls without taking into account the next four rolls).

Answer (score 1):

The probability that none of the triple rolls gives $18$, i.e. the probability that none of the triple rolls is $666$ is

$$\left(1-\frac1{6^3}\right)^6.$$

So, the probability that at least one of them is a triple six is

$$1-\left(1-\frac1{6^3}\right)^6\approx 0.02746
.$$

Answer (score 1):

No.   Not quite.   It is the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^6 \dbinom 6 i\left(\dfrac{1}{6^3}\right)^i\left(\dfrac{6^3-1}{6^3}\right)^{6-i}$$

Which comes from the fact that the count of triple-six among six rolls of three dice is Binomially distributed.

But that's awkward to work with.   Rather, it would be tidier if you were to calculate the probability for *not* obtaining *zero* of triple-six among the six rolls.